# GLSL Texture LOD

Tags: glsl, shader

I am trying to accomplish a LOD of textures program in GLSL. However, there is a lack of examples on the internet of how such shaders would work. I have tried to use the functions described [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/textureLod.xml), but the shader just fails to compile. Does anyone have an example or link to an example of how texture LOD can be done in GLSL?

Comment: What is the error you get when compiling?

Comment: Note that you can and should specify a constant bias just with the regular texture function. textureLod is for computed/dynamic bias.

Comment: @starmole, I am not sure what error I am getting when compiling the shader.  Most likely it is a small mistake due to my lack of GLSL knowledge.